# Retrieve email address from Parse User class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to get the email address of the user from the parse database using the `objectId`.

```
ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "EMqw4TOQ0c");
        query.getInBackground("email",new GetCallback() { 
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            email= parseObject.getString("email");
        }
    });
        }
    });
```

I am trying to use the `getInBackground()` method but it gives an error.

```
03-29 02:13:33.600  19659-19659/com.parse.starter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:155)
            at com.parse.starter.Dummy.getEmail(Dummy.java:54)
            at com.parse.starter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.getInBackground("EMqw4TOQ0c",new GetCallback<ParseUser>() { 
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser parseObject, ParseException e) {
            email= parseObject.getEmail();
        }
    });
        }
    });
```

There are three differences:

1. The first parameter to `getInBackground` is the object id
2. The query specifies that it will return a ParseUser
3. There is a special method to get the user's email address

Comment: Still it returns a null value for the email

Comment: Do you get a user object back with the correct username?  If not, then that needs to be fixed.  If so, did you verify in the browser that the user has an email address?

Comment: hi  @nasch please check this if you can , thnaks   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse