# ANDROID: email client receiver email id empty in android-parse

Tags: java, android, email, parsing, android-service

I'm using android- parse server in app.  below is parse db screenshot of email column .
the email column is after the hidden password column in database .

### [image: parse database screenshot]

**my problem is**

---

when i retrieve email ids to email client,
email is null even if the email column has emails .

---

note : in the app in another place (another table) i'm pulling email ids to email client in same manner, but there mail is showing well .. only here the problem occurs.

if anyone knows please help ?

> this is email column in parse database

```
 try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = parseObjectToJson(object);
                        Log.d("Object", jsonObject.toString());
                        Log.d("Email", "+" + object.get("email"));
                        personNumber = jsonObject.getString("telephone");
                        personEmail = jsonObject.getString("email");
                    }catch (JSONException je){

                    }catch (ParseException pe){

                    }
```

> this is  email button

```
  emailPerson = (Button)findViewById(R.id.individualEmail);
            emailPerson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                    i.setType("plain/text");
                    i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {personEmail});
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            if(personEmail==null || personEmail.equals("")  || personEmail.equals(" ")){
                emailPerson.setClickable(false);
                emailPerson.setEnabled(false);
                emailPerson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                emailPerson.setEnabled(true);
                emailPerson.setClickable(true);
                emailPerson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

---

> here it is working fine but this is a different table in same database . >in this table there is no hidden password field

```
try{
                            corporateEmail = jsonObject.getString("email");
                            if(corporateEmail == null || corporateEmail.equals("")){
                                emailCorporate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                emailCorporate.setEnabled(false);
                                emailCorporate.setClickable(false);
                            }
```

---

```
emailCorporate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.corporateEmail);
        emailCorporate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                i.setType("plain/text");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {corporateEmail});
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

---

```
 private JSONObject parseObjectToJson(ParseObject parseObject) throws ParseException, JSONException, com.parse.ParseException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        parseObject.fetchIfNeeded();
        Set<String> keys = parseObject.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            Object objectValue = parseObject.get(key);
            if (objectValue instanceof ParseObject) {
                jsonObject.put(key, parseObjectToJson(parseObject.getParseObject(key)));
            } else if (objectValue instanceof ParseRelation) {
            } else {
                jsonObject.put(key, objectValue.toString());
            }
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: try to log the ParseException you will be able to know the error

Comment: no error showing. only null is return . so in this code if null i have added hiding .. but actually email ids are there .. ? is it because email column is after password column ? @Ali Taouni

Comment: maybe because you have to change object.get("email") to object.getString("email") in the Log

Comment: no bro same code work in other table in parse but that column does not have hidden password .. is it possible hidden password column prevent to get data ?   @Ali Taouni

Comment: can you print your json object you can see what data is there

Comment: empty object @jitesh mohite only for email others have objects

Comment: @FaizalMohamed thats the issue not the email. we need to find why object is getting null

Comment: yes, @jitesh mohite as you can see in screen shots email column is after hidden password column .. i think password is blocking accessing other columns .. because only logged in users email is working

Comment: if it is working for logged in user it should be good for you @Faizal Mohamed. is there anything you want to help you.

Comment: hi, @jitesh mohite no i need it to be worked for not logged users also thats the issue here .. if i loged it i shuld b able to see others emails also .. but it is showing only logged pesrons email .. others null

Comment: @FaizalMohamed their might be issue in your parser setting. you can check their

Comment: sory for late @jitesh mohite can you explain  iddnt get u mean seetings to parse sever .. ? in java code ?

Comment: are you using these http://parseplatform.org/docs/android/guide/

Comment: @jitesh mohite yes bro .  another place also I'm getting email id lke this that is working fine only this table casusing problm  i'll edit the question check ples

Comment: parseObjectToJson(object) what is these object can you see it and what it contains in these case and compare it with other table

Comment: hi @jitesh mohite i added in question pleas chek

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I'm wondering about your approach.  Why are you converting to JSONObject rather than using ParseObject subclasses?

Comment: before it was parseObject but , I could not load data. so I thought to store in JSONObject . Is it possible to retrieve email field of a user from parse User class  when logged in different user ?  @nasch

Comment: Yes, reading should be possible unless you've changed the default ACL. "We never allow users to write each other's data, but they can read it by default." http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iii-are-you-on-the-list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if jsonObject is not null check to see if the parse database you are pulling your data from has the the "email" tag

Comment: screen shot is in question please check . . email tag is after the hidden password column is it causing impossible  to retrieve email ids ?  @Oniyide Ibukun Olaoluwa

Comment: try  Log.d("Object", jsonObject.toString()); check if the result contains email if so, check through the result to pinpoint the excat location of it, u can post the response so we can debug it together

Comment: hi , no result is null  @Oniyide Ibukun Olaoluwa